# How do you switch from importing objects from tns-core-modules to @nativescript/core?

Tags: import, module, nativescript, migrate

Okay, so I ran the command "ns migrate" to use a newer version of nativescript. What this does is remove the tns-core-modules dependency, which means I can't use it to import things anymore. Supposedly we're supposed to use @nativescript/core instead, but the problem is when I try to import objects @nativescript/core doesn't work and I'm greeted with "cannot find module '@nativescript/core' or its corresponding type declarations".

For example, this will not work:

```
import { Label } from "@nativescript/core";
```

But with the tns-core-modules dependency it worked and was as simple as:

```
import { Label } from "tns-core-modules/ui/label"
```

After running the ns migrate command it remove tns-core-modules and updates @nativescript/core to 7.3.0

Am I importing incorrectly??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
run npm install @nativescript/core
```

Then this should work

```
import { Label } from "@nativescript/core";
```

I use

```
import { ApplicationSettings, ImageSource } from '@nativescript/core';
```

in my recent project

Comment: That did it. Wow... I swear I thought I already had it installed... Silly me. I'll upvote and accept as answer in 4 minutes when it lets me

Comment: How would I change this import? const { fromObject } = require('tns-core-modules/data/observable')

Comment: No difference use import { fromObject } from "@nativescript/core";